# Jasper Reports - Parsing Double values from JSON

Tags: json, jasper-reports, double, number-formatting

I am using Jasper Reports 6.0.1 with Jaspersoft Studio.

I have a report with a subreport. The subreport correctly gets the data set from the main report, with values:
- string
- double

I have problems with correctly displaying the double values in the report.
So the Json contains values like:

'doubleValue': '0.431'

The field 'doubleValue' is correctly defined in the subreport:

```
<field name="doubleValue" class="java.lang.Double">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[doubleValue]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

And the 'doubleValue' seems correctly used in the report:

```
<textField pattern="#0.00">
                <reportElement x="690" y="0" width="75" height="30" uuid="d265ebec-6fa7-421e-8d58-c7f2d32eea6b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{doubleValue}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

The doubleValue seems to be correctly formatted in the output:
'3.00'

BUT:
the source of the field value was 3.41. 
So I have inspected the values deeply, and all values are formatted as 'x.00' no matter what is behind the decimal separator.

Please help me, what am I doing wrong?

I need the data correctly exported to XLSX (so it knows there is a number in the cell), and I am using the following option for this:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
```

Comment: I have tried you pattern exporting to excel and I have no problem with it (jasper report v6). NOTE furthermore in excel the real value is with in the cell (hence es, 3.414545 and only the format in excel is set to display 2 number (personalized format #.00)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These problem's often occurs when decimal separator changes on the basis of localization es. .(dot) is decimal separator in the US but in Italy the decimal separator is , (comma)

However jasper report (v 6) should handle this without problem, your pattern should  be in US format and jasper report will export in `Locale.getDefault()` format (also applying correct pattern in excel).

So there should be **nothing wrong** with your **jrxml**.

However note that a `JsonDataSource` will use `Locale.getDefault()` format so if you have an Italian Local the `Double` number es. 12.234 will be interpreted to 12234 (hence thousand).

In this case you need to set the **Local** to the `JsonDataSource` es.

```
JsonDataSource ds = new JsonDataSource(new File("example.json"));
ds.setLocale(Locale.US);
```

To correctly parse your numbers.

Comment: Just to add to your answer... I had a scenario where I had JSON in en-US and wanted to use it in a subreport that was running in a JVM with locale pt-BR. I couldn't find a way to create the `JsonDataSource` and set the locale as you mentioned in order to pass it to the sub report. However, it *is* possible to pass the JSON as an input stream through the JSON_INPUT_STREAM parameter and set the locale through the JSON_LOCALE parameter.